# Support ticketing system for multiple clients

Tags: issue-tracker, support-tracker

We provide technical support for multiple partner companies.  These companies will have 1-n staff members that contact us for support.  We need a system with the following features:

**Essential**

- Aggregation of user accounts and tickets under client company; All users belonging to company A can see all tickets raised by other company A users but no tickets belonging to other companies.
- File attachments on tickets
- Email notifications
- Ticket Status: open, closed etc

**Desirable**

- Mobile UI
- Free
- Brandable; change logos, style etc

Ideally it will be a SaaS solution so we won't have to get involved in the technical side of things.  However, we could install in on a VM in which case it must run on Linux.  We can pay a modest amount for it. say less than £100GBP (approx $150USD) pcm.

Comment: What OS must it run on? What price are you willing to pay? Are you looking for a "native software", or a web-based solution? Have you checked related questions – e.g. those tagged [issue-tracker](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/issue-tracker) or [support-tracker](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support-tracker)?

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to check out [Planio](https://plan.io/) which has all of the required features + concierge level customer support. Planio is based on the Open Source project Redmine and we're one of its major contributors. We've been running since 2009 and serve over 1,500 customers now. We're a sustainable, bootstrapped and owner-operated company, so we won't go anywhere anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is EasyRedmine, which is a plugin to boost Redmine (the basic version). It covers all the cases you specified.